# Toggle bolt stuck in the ceiling with mounting plate

Tags: screws, hanging, drywall-anchor

I bought 3 LED flat panel ceiling lights from Costco.  2 panels installed perfectly. One one panel, 3 toggle bolts are installed perfectly, but 1 toggle bolt is stuck and I cannot screw it into the ceiling with about 1/2 inch gap.

The toggle bolt seems to get loose and cannot grab the ceiling and I cannot screw it into the ceiling.

I am wondering what I should do?  Unscrew it and try again?  It took me a while to make the toggle bolt into the ceiling, so my intention is to get it done by keep trying.

Any suggestions?

Update: I can push the bolt all the way to ceiling, so it does not hit a frame.

[image]

[image]

Comment: After you get this resolved by using the accepted answer, **never** use a plain toggle bolt again.  Use something like this instead: http://www.amazon.com/TOGGLER-SNAPTOGGLE-Zinc-Plated-Channel-Fastener/dp/B0051IARUE/  You can remove and re-insert the screw, and you set them into place *under* whatever it is you are trying to mount to the wall.  Makes life much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ArchonOSX, you need to pull on the screw as you screw it in. But, be careful if isn't going deep enough. You could be hitting a wire or plumbing or the screw may just be too long for a framing piece.

If that's the case you need to remove the first screw & start over with a shortened screw. Thread the wing on past where you want to cut or snap the screw end off. Cut or snap the screw end off & you're ready to install.

Comment: It's my suspicion that the bolt is hitting framing as well. Remove it and start fresh.

Comment: I added my original question to mention that only one toggle bolt gave me a hard time.  It is possible that it hit a frame!

Comment: Yep, that's the impression that I got. And Yep, there could be a stretcher that's part of the framing that you could be hitting or some support cleat that's there or it could even be insulation or construction debris that you lifted with the screw that's stopping the screw's progress. You're doing everything else right if you got 7 out of 8, so try a new toggle bolt with a maximum of 1-inch taken off. Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: Final solution: I ended up using a plier to cut and snap the screw head off.  I tried to saw  it off but it is hard to hold the screw steady and maneuver the metal saw.  I then placed a new toggle bolt and easily inserted it into the same hole and secured the mounting plate.

Comment: Beautiful!!! I was just wondering today how you made out. Great Job & I'm glad everything finally got completely secured!

Answer (score 2):

To either screw it in or out you need to maintain tension on it to keep the toggle wing from spinning.

Pull down on your plate with light pressure until the wing stops spinning.

As it gets snug you can release the extra pressure.

Good luck!

Comment: I spent 30 minutes of trying.  -:).  The problem is the wing kept spinning.  Will give it a try from your advise and post results afterwards.   Thanks !!

Comment: From your picture I would try to carefully insert a putty knife (or butter knife you don't care about) under the head of the bolt that is spinning and pry it up enough to get tension on the toggle.